# Force Jetty 7.0 to Response with HTTP/1.0

Tags: java, http, jetty

I'm using Jetty 7.0 embedded mode and looking for a way to force Jetty to response with **HTTP 1.0** and not **1.1** (which seems to be the default).

Is there any setting I can use, to control the protocol version on the server response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way to get Jetty to send HTTP/1.0 responses is to have the client to send it HTTP/1.0 requests.

By way of justification, consider this paragraph from the HTTP 1.1 specification:

> An application that sends a request or response message that includes HTTP-Version of "HTTP/1.1" MUST be at least conditionally compliant with this specification. Applications that are at least conditionally compliant with this specification SHOULD use an HTTP-Version of "HTTP/1.1" in their messages, and MUST do so for any message that is not compatible with HTTP/1.0. For more details on when to send specific HTTP-Version values, see RFC 2145.

In other words, if a client sends HTTP/1.1 requests, it must be capable of dealing with HTTP/1.1 responses.  If it is not, then it is violating the HTTP specification ... and all bets are off.

Comment: I've check it with curl, and it seems that Jetty responds with HTTP 1.1 to HTTP 1.0 requests:

#curl -I --http1.0 http://jettyweb
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 29588
Server: Jetty(7.0.0.v20091005)